# ¿como proceso un Timeout de petición python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Estoy utilizando la librería requests en python (2.7), preciso configurar la petición estableciendo tiempo de espera de conexión y de lectura, y estoy usando un ejemplo del sitio del proyecto python-requests.org, pero lanza un error: "timeout on request" aun y cuando estoy intentando ir contra google. Alguna idea?

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://google.com', timeout=(20, 60))
```

Estoy usando la versión de la librería 1.0.2

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola, al parecer no existe esa versión de `requests`, ¿estás seguro que es la 1.11 y no la 0.11 o 1.1?

Comment: Si, es la versión 1.11.6

Comment: @perodriguezl intento instalar esa versión y me arroja: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==1.11.6`

Comment: usa asi el atributo timeout `requests.get('http://google.com', timeout=0.5)`

Comment: tienes toda la razon @RicardoD.Quiroga estaba viendo un dato incorrecto la version actual del server es 1.0.2

Comment: debo usar ambos parametros @RicardoD.Quiroga uno es el tiempo de conexion y el otro es de lectura. si lo uso como tu indicas funciona bien.

Comment: ahora recién revise bien esta correcto la tupla es para tiempos de respuesta y lectura, por las dudas no estas corriendo en windows, puede que tu firewall este bloqueando las peticiones salientes de python

Comment: no, como te digo usando solo: timeout=0.5 funciona el problema es cuando hago timeout=(20, 60), es decir no debe haber problemas con firewall, y estoy usando ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que para tu versión, no estaba implementada esa característica. Observa el código de esa [versión](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/v1.0.2/requests/api.py#L17):

```
def request(method, url, **kwargs):
    """Constructs and sends a :class:`Request <Request>`.
    Returns :class:`Response <Response>` object.
    :param method: method for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param params: (optional) Dictionary or bytes to be sent in the query string for the :class:`Request`.
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary or bytes to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param headers: (optional) Dictionary of HTTP Headers to send with the :class:`Request`.
    :param cookies: (optional) Dict or CookieJar object to send with the :class:`Request`.
    :param files: (optional) Dictionary of 'name': file-like-objects (or {'name': ('filename', fileobj)}) for multipart encoding upload.
    :param auth: (optional) Auth tuple to enable Basic/Digest/Custom HTTP Auth.
    :param timeout: (optional) Float describing the timeout of the request.
    :param allow_redirects: (optional) Boolean. Set to True if POST/PUT/DELETE redirect following is allowed.
    :param proxies: (optional) Dictionary mapping protocol to the URL of the proxy.
    :param verify: (optional) if ``True``, the SSL cert will be verified. A CA_BUNDLE path can also be provided.
    :param stream: (optional) if ``False``, the response content will be immediately downloaded.
    :param cert: (optional) if String, path to ssl client cert file (.pem). If Tuple, ('cert', 'key') pair.
    """

    session = sessions.Session()
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
```

A diferencia de la [versión actual](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/api/?highlight=timeout) con respecto a ese parámero (usando una tupla):

```
:param timeout: (optional) How many seconds to wait for the server to send data
        before giving up, as a float, or a :ref:`(connect timeout, read
        timeout) <timeouts>` tuple.
```

Por lo tanto, me parece que tienes solo dos opciones:

1. Usar simplemente `timeout` con un dato de tipo `float`
2. Actualizar a una versión reciente que soporte dicho comportamiento

   Si estás usando `pip` puedes hacer:

   ```
   $ pip install --upgrade requests
   ```

Comment: Excelente, muy acertado, se me paso verificar eso, lamentablemente no puedo hacer upgrade a ese paquete ya que en el server de prod esa es la version que esta.